# Using prototyping to alter functionality of existing jQuery functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype-programming, dom-manipulation

I would like to alter the functionality of `$.prepend()` (and probably `$.append()`) for the purpose of having an "on DOM change event".

Can I do something as simple as:

```
$.prepend = function() { alert('Hello World'); };
```

Or do I need to use the `$.extend()` function or `$.prototype.prepend` or `$.fn.prepend`?

[I realise I'll need to include the original source for the `prepend()` function in my new one otherwise jQuery will break!]

**EDIT :: Final Solution**

For those who are interested:

```
$.extend($, {
domChangeStack: [],
onDomChange: function(selector, fn, unbind, removeFromStack) {
    /* Needs to store: selector, function, unbind flag, removeFromStack flag */
    jQuery.domChangeStack.push([selector, fn, unbind, removeFromStack]);
},
domChangeEvent: function() {
    /* Ideally should only affect inserted HTML/altered DOM, but this doesn't */
    var stackItem, newStack = [];

    while (stackItem = jQuery.domChangeStack.pop()) {
        var selector = stackItem[0],
            fn = stackItem[1],
            unbind = stackItem[2],
            remove = stackItem[3];

        if (unbind) { $(selector).unbind(); }
        // Need to pass the jQuery object as fn is anonymous
        fn($(selector));
        if (!remove) { newStack.push(stackItem); }
    }

    jQuery.domChangeStack = newStack;

    // Show something happened!
    console.log("domChangeEvent: stack size = " + newStack.length);
}
});

$.fn.prepend = function() {

    var result = this.domManip(arguments, true, function( elem ) {
        if ( this.nodeType === 1 ) {
            this.insertBefore( elem, this.firstChild );
        }
    });

    // Need to actually alter DOM above before calling the DOMChange event
    $.domChangeEvent();

    return result;
};
```

And usage:

```
/* Run the given function on the elements found by the selector,
 *  don't run unbind() beforehand and don't pop this DOMChange
 *  event off the stack.
 */
$.onDomChange(".element_class", function(jObj) {
       jObj.do_something_awesome();
   }, false, false);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which method you want to use depends on how much you need to change. Since [`.prepend`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) is merely a method that resides in `.fn` you don't have to mess with the prototype.

I most cases its enough to rename the original method, create your own function that does what you want and end with a call to the original function, like this:

```
var orgPrepend = $.fn.prepend;
$.fn.prepend = function(){
    // Do what you want here

    // Call org prepend and return
    return orgPrepend.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

*Note: `.apply` and `.call` are more or less identical. The only difference is that `.apply` passes arguments by reference while `.call` passes them by value, so I prefer to use `.apply` before `.call` where possible. [See MDC for reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)*

But if you look at the source of jQuery (see [src/manipulation.js](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js)) you'll see that this method is very small so you can just implement it directly.

In the next example I will use [`.extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) instead, but it's not a must; you could just replace it like in the first example.

```
$.extend($.fn, {
    prepend: function() {
        // Do what you want here
        console.log("prepend was called");
        // Execute domManip
        return this.domManip(arguments, true, function( elem ) {
            if ( this.nodeType === 1 ) {
                this.insertBefore( elem, this.firstChild );
            }
        });
    }
});
```

You can override `.domManip` or any other method in the same way, like in the following example. You'll probably see why I prefer to use `.extend` here.

```
var _domManip = $.fn.domManip;
$.extend($.fn, {
    domManip: function() {
        // Do what you want here
        console.log("domManip was called");
        _domManip.apply(this, arguments);
    },
    prepend: function() {
        // Do what you want here
        console.log("prepend was called");
        // Execute domManip
        return this.domManip(arguments, true, function( elem ) {
            if ( this.nodeType === 1 ) {
                this.insertBefore( elem, this.firstChild );
            }
        });
    }
});
```

See [test case on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/a3QsK/)

Answer (score 2):

I've made a little test and it seems that you must replace `$.fn.prepend`. Anyway if you want you can do something like:

```
var old=$.fn.prepend;
$.fn.prepend=function(){
   //Trigger DOMchange event
   old.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

In this way you can wrap the old prepend function in a new one without rewrite the function code.

Comment: of course. I tend to elaborate on my answers to make them generally applicable, even though the main question itself has been answered. Hopefully that helps others with similar questions :)